# Dictionary is empty after declaring it and populating

Tags: vba, dictionary, declaration

I'm not so good with VBA, thus I'm suspecting an issue with declaring and later on using the dictionary.

I've taken a different approach. Created two functions to creat the dicts.

The for loop first is checking if the Control in userform is textbox, than is getting column number (dict_col) and checks if needs to be formatted as date (dict_for).

However each time the second dict seems to be empty... When I check content of each dict separately (before the loop), it shows correct values.

```
Public Function import_columns(rng As Variant) As Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count_rows As Long
    Dim dict_k As String, dict_i As String

    count_rows = rng.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To count_rows
        dict_k = rng(i, 2)
        dict_i = rng(i, 1)
        dict.Add dict_k, dict_i
    Next i

    Set import_columns = dict

End Function

Public Function import_format(rng As Variant) As Dictionary
    Dim dict_f As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count_rows As Long

    count_rows = rng.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To count_rows
        dict_f(rng(i, 1)) = 0
    Next i

    Set import_format = dict_f

End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng_col As Range
Dim rng_format As Range
Dim dc_value As Integer
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim ctrlType As String
Dim ctrl_name As String
Dim key As Variant


Dim dict_col As Dictionary
Dim dict_for As Dictionary



Set rng_col = Application.Union(Range("columns_mark").Columns(3), Range("columns_mark").Columns(2))
Set rng_format = Arkusz25.Range("H1").CurrentRegion

Set dict_col = import_columns(rng_col)
Set dict_for = import_format(rng_format)

'Me.Results.Enabled = False


ListBox1.RowSource = "lista"
txt_results = ListBox1.ListCount

For Each key In dict_col.Keys
    'If dict_col.Exists(key) Then
        Debug.Print key
        Debug.Print dict_col(key)
    'End If
Next key


ctrlType = "TextBox"
For Each ctrl In Results.Controls
    ctrl_name = ctrl.Name
    If TypeName(ctrl) = ctrlType Then
        dc_value = dict_col(ctrl_name)
        If dict_for.Exists(ctrl_name) Then
                ctrl = Format(Val(ListBox1.List(0, dc_value - 1)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
            Else
                ctrl = ListBox1.List(0, dc_value - 1)
            End If
        ctrl.Enabled = False
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Comment: Try setting the value to a string variable first - `sValue = rng_format.Item(row, 1)` and then `list_format.Add sValue, "date"` - and do something similar when reading from it as well - Seems odd you would want all the values to be `"date"` tho - if that's the case, you can just use `.Exists`

Comment: I've adjusted the code and using variable in creating the dict and later on when in the for loop. And the dictionary "list_format" is not empty when checking before the loop, but any moment I try to get any value from it inside the loop, it shows as empty...

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Please, at least, show the declarations for the variables rng and rng_format.

Comment: added the declaration part.

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: Yes. I can use the dictionary in the `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` , but when trying to use both in the loop, the seocnd one shows as empty.